# Insert query - executeUpdate returning -1

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I am trying to insert records into SQL Server using jdbc conn (in java).
I am able to insert into SQL, if I manually copy the query statement in the java file. But its not inserting from the code?

Please help, where am I committing mistake?

> 

```
           PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;

        if (conn != null) {                 
            System.out.println("Connection Successful!");             
        } 

        //Create a Statement object
        Statement sql_stmt = conn.createStatement();

         //Create a Statement object
        Statement sql_stmt_1 = conn.createStatement();

        //Result Set for Prouduct Table
        ResultSet rs  = sql_stmt.executeQuery("SELECT MAX(ID), MAX(RG_ID), MAX(WG_ID) FROM " + strDBName + ".[dbo].Product");

        if ( rs.next() ) {     
            // Retrieve the auto generated key(s).     
            intID = rs.getInt(1); 
            intRG_ID = rs.getInt(2); 
            intWG_ID = rs.getInt(3); 
        }

        for (int iCount = 0 ;iCount < arrListLevel_1_Unique.size(); iCount++)
        {

         //Result Set for Prouduct Table


        sql_stmt_1.executeUpdate("\n IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM " + strDBName + ".[dbo].Product WHERE [Name] NOT LIKE '" + arrListLevel_1_Unique.get(iCount) + "') "
                + "\nINSERT INTO " + strDBName + ".[dbo].Product ([Name] ,"
                + "[RG_ID],[WG_ID],[Parent_Product]) "
                + "VALUES ( '" + arrListLevel_1_Unique.get(iCount) + "',"
                + + (intWG_ID + intRowIncrement) + ", " + (intWG_ID + intRowIncrement + 1) + ", 5828)");


        intRowIncrement++ ;
        }

    rs.close();
        sql_stmt.close();
        sql_stmt_1.close();


        //Close the database connection
        conn.close();
```

Comment: can you extract your SQL Query and and just post that? Too much code I think.

Comment: If you want help, **you** need to reduce the code to the smallest possible fragment that illustrates the problem

Comment: Hi All, I edited the code for the readability. Is sql_stmt_1.executeUpdate (); is not the right call to insert data into sql table ?

Comment: @Ramm: You have `NOT EXISTS` and `WHERE Name NOT LIKE`. Are you sure you need both negatives?

Comment: @ypercube : I had it for extra validation. But the insert query if I run in query analyzer, it works. This way its not inserting into the table.THanks

Comment: Then try with `executeQuery`, not `executeUpdate`. Not sure which method accepts the `IF EXISTS...` statement.

Comment: @Ypercube: If I cant use the IF EXISTS there, hows the better way to check if the record with that [Name] doesnt exist and insert it. I tried with ExecuteQuery, it showed exception "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The statement did not return a result set." Thanks

Comment: @Ramm: check my answer for removing the `IF EXISTS`

Comment: @Ramm let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1615/discussion-between-ypercube-and-ramm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two plus signs `+` in the fifth row:

```
+ + (intWG_ID + intRowIncrement) + ...
```

---

Otherwise, the problem may lie in the `IF ...` statement. You can try this instead:

```
    sql_stmt_1.executeUpdate(
        " INSERT INTO " + strDBName + ".[dbo].Product ([Name] ,"
      + "[RG_ID],[WG_ID],[Parent_Product]) "
      + " SELECT '" + arrListLevel_1_Unique.get(iCount) + "',"
      + (intWG_ID + intRowIncrement) + ", "
      + (intWG_ID + intRowIncrement + 1) + ", 5828 "
      + " WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM " + strDBName
      + ".[dbo].Product WHERE [Name] LIKE '"
      + arrListLevel_1_Unique.get(iCount) + "') "
    ) ;
```

Comment: Thanks Ypercube for the solution. The records are inserted now. But the point for me is, I already have these records in the table, in future I expect more data. In that case, if I insert it will be a duplicate data. Is any alternate for executing the query with "IF EXISTS" ?? Thanks

Comment: @Ramm: That's why I added the `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... WHERE NOT EXISTS ...` example. But I still think that you need `WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT ... WHERE Name **LIKE** ...)`. Note the **`LIKE`** vs the **`NOT LIKE`**.

Comment: You can also add a UNIQUE constraint on the `Product.Name` field. You won't have to worry about checking the INSERTs for duplicate names. The database will be doing that.

Comment: Thanks @ypercube. Somehow your modified statement also didnt update the table. I have the ID column which is identity on that field. I cant add Unique constraint on the [Name] column as the DB is designed that way :(.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem lies on the "\n", have you tried eliminating those 2 of "\n" and see if it's working?

Actually this kind of implementation (building SQL string with string concatenation) is really bad. At first is prone to SQL injection, and then secondly you will have problem if the value to be inserted contains character single quote or ampersand.

Instead, you should use "prepare statement".

And it's tidier to store the SQL string into a variable before executing it. So that you can log it (for debug purpose), roughly something like this:

```
String sqlCommand = "select * from " + tableName;
System.out.println(sqlCommand);
sqlStatement.executeUpdate(sqlCommand);
```

P.S. it is not advised to use system.out.println for debug, you should implement a proper logging system.

Comment: I had the same prepared statement initially. To shorten the code, i added the query string to the ExecuteUpdate statement.Thanks